# how to include background images in jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-animate

With this code,there is no image coming in the background.What is wrong with the animation function here?Codepen [Link](http://codepen.io/asinha/pen/bqNmgM).Is there a way to put different images in the background by a button click function.

```
var colors=["http://publicdomainarchive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/public-domain-images-free-stock-photos-002-1000x667.jpg","https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSCJmPmIMiKQPy0M68oDKYuzoQT6pT4kL37vH8DzS3z36fYgza0"];
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").on("click",function(){
      getQuote();
});
});

function getQuote(){
      var color=Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
  $("html body").animate({
      backgroundImage:colors[color],
      color:colors[color]
    },1000);    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't animate the `backgroundImage` property with jQuery's `.animate()` method, second the `backgroundImage` property should be:

`backgroundImage: 'url(/path/to/image.jpg)'`

If you need a new background image with every click, then make another array of urls to use:

```
var colors = ["#16a085", "#27ae60", "#2c3e50"];
var images = ["image-1", "image-2", "image-3"];

var color = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
var image = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);


$("body").css({
    backgroundImage: "url("+images[image]+")",
    color: colors[color]
});
```

jQuery doesn't support animating colors without using jQuery UI. You can animate the color with with a simple bit of CSS:

```
.message, .author {
  transition: color 1000ms ease 0ms;
}
```

Comment: what should i do for my image to cover the whole window of the browser?I tried backgroundSize:'100% 100%'.But it isn't working @karl

Comment: You need to define a width and height for the body: http://codepen.io/Mobius1/pen/VpYoVY